# How to find a vector with two 3d points?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors

A:(2,3,1); B:(8,-2,4); C:(3,0,5).

find **a** so $\vec A\vec B$ is orthogonal to $\vec A \vec B + a. \vec A \vec C $.

I think the answer is $(\vec A\vec B) .(\vec A \vec B + a. \vec A \vec C) = 0$ and then find **a**.(if this isn't the answer please tell me.)

but how can I write or find $\vec A \vec B$. I think with matrices because that's what we are studying now.

I'm sorry if this is a beginner question.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, note that
$$\begin{align}\vec{AB} &= \vec{B} - \vec{A} \\&= (8-2,-2-3,4-1) \\&= (6,-5,3)\end{align}$$

$$
\begin{align}
\vec{AC} &= \vec C - \vec A \\
&= (3-2,0-3,5-1) \\
&= (1,-3,4)
\end{align}$$
$$\begin{align}
\vec{AB} + a\vec{AC} &= (6,-5,3) + a(1,-3,4) \\&= (6+a,-5-3a,3+4a)\end{align}$$
Then, as you have mentioned, we need to have $\vec{AB}\cdot\left(\vec{AB} + a\vec{AC}\right) = 0:$
$$(6,-5,3)\cdot (6+a,-5-3a,3+4a) = 0 \\
36+6a + 25+15a + 9+12a = 0 \\ 33a + 70 = 0 \implies a = -\frac{70}{33}$$

Comment: thanks a lot, it makes sense now

Answer (score 0):

First, welcome to the community. Here's the answer to your question:

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}2\cr 3\cr 1\end{pmatrix}$, $B=\begin{pmatrix}8\cr -2\cr 4\end{pmatrix}$ and $C=\begin{pmatrix}3\cr 0\cr 5\end{pmatrix}$. You can compute $\vec{AB}=B-A=\begin{pmatrix}6\cr -5\cr 3\end{pmatrix}$ and $\vec{AC}=C-A=\begin{pmatrix}1\cr -3\cr 4\end{pmatrix}$

Note that the dot product between two vectors $\vec{u},\vec{v}$ is given by $\vec{u}\cdot \vec{v} =|u||v|cos(\theta)$, so
$\vec u \cdot \vec v = 0 \implies \cos \theta  = 0 \implies \theta = \pi/2 \;\;(90^\circ)$.

This way you can find $a$ as you describe in the question:

$(\vec {AB}) .(\vec {AB} + a  \vec {AC})=\,\left( 4\,a+3\right) +6\,\left( a+6\right) -5\,\left( -3\,a-5\right) = 0$ . This means $a=-\frac{70}{33}$.

Comment: thanks a lot, this is an amazing community